# ionic ngIf return statement looping forever

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to check ngIf statement if true then it show icon that I get from webservices, but when I try build it and run it on android phone it seems that function is looping forever.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let periode of items" (click)="dismiss(periode)">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img *ngIf="checkIcon(periode.img)=='1'" class="image-icon" src="{{periode.img}}" style="border-radius:0%;">
        <img *ngIf="checkIcon(periode.img)=='0'" class="image-icon" src="assets/imgs/home/App-Icon.png" style="border-radius:0%;">
      </ion-avatar>
      <button ion-item value="{{periode.Productid}}"></button>
      <ion-label><a style="color:#838383;font-size:13px;font-weight:400">{{ periode.Productdesc }}</a> </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
checkIcon(icoimg:any) {
    var vars;

        this.file.checkFile('file:///android_asset/www/', icoimg).then(
          (files) => {
        return vars === "1";
          }
    ).catch (
          (err) => {
        return vars === "0";
          }
    );
    }
```

I don't have idea why it don't work, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your checkIcon is not returning anything, it should return the result inorder to get ngIf working, add a return in front of the call

```
return this.file.checkFile('file:///android_asset/www/', icoimg).then
```

Comment: so, i don't need to return vars === "1"; again?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert promise to observable, so that in template *ngIf we can access the value using async.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
  checkIcon(icoimg:any) {
    var vars;

        return from(this.file.checkFile('file:///android_asset/www/', icoimg).then(
          (files) => {
        return vars === "1";
          }
    ).catch (
          (err) => {
        return vars === "0";
          }
    ));
    }
```

Template:

```
<ion-avatar item-start>
        <img *ngIf="(checkIcon(periode.img) | async) =='1'" class="image-icon" src="{{periode.img}}" style="border-radius:0%;">
        <img *ngIf="(checkIcon(periode.img) | async) == '0'" class="image-icon" src="assets/imgs/home/App-Icon.png" style="border-radius:0%;">
      </ion-avatar>
```

Comment: you need to return '1' right. instead of vars === "1". this may convert to boolean.

Comment: is it possible to create stackblitz. will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your 1st question why its calling multi times so first wrote in ng-for that's why its calling every time of iteration, second ng-if always looking for `change detection` when something change in modal or variable its triggers. so if you want to check only once image available or not write code like this...

```
<ion-avatar item-start>
    <img (load)="checkIcon($event, periode.img)" class="image-icon" src="{{periode.img}}" style="border-radius:0%;">
  </ion-avatar>
```

Ts Side

```
checkIcon(event,icoimg){
   this.file.checkFile('file:///android_asset/www/', icoimg).then(
      (files) => {
     event.target.style.display = 'block';
      }
).catch (
      (err) => {
     event.target.style.display = 'none';
      }
);
}
```

Comment: I want to change that img using default assets file when I can't found it on android asset folder

Comment: Not getting you, so are you want to check only image are available or not?

Comment: need to check when there's no "A.png" images on android asset folder then replace it with "B.png", I'm using return in *ngIf